# JQuery Datepicker throws a random Type Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uidatepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I got an JQuery Datepicker Issue,

on around every 50th page reload i get an error message, when i want to select an date from the JQuery Datepicker:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'find'
```

When the Datepicker is clicked then the field gets not filled with the date.

**This issue only happens under this conditions:**

- when clicking on the  element of the date selection
- only in Chrome
- the error is extremy rare, i need around 15min time to reproduce again
- if the JQuery is loaded via CDN (async) or from our server the error is still there
- we tryed to explict call the datepicker when the page is .ready() but doesn`t helped

**Used JQuery versions:**

- jquery.min.js | jQuery JavaScript Library v1.5.2
- jquery-ui.min.js | jQuery UI - v1.8.21
- jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js | jQuery UI 1.8.15
- jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js | Version 0.9.6

The only thing we now see is to update JQuery but we only want to do this as very last solution otherwiese we need change a lot of code.

Maybe someone already faced the problem.

Regards

**//Edit:**

- i removed the second import of jquery ui
- i updated the version to jQuery UI 1.8.21
- i loaded the validation.js and  tinymce.js (with the old `this.find` call) first

still not working

Comment: Maybe something to do with the order in which scripts are loaded and caching. Try clearing your browser cache and refresh...hopefully that will reproduce the problem everytime and then you can debug.

Comment: So even when the cache is clean sometimes this error apears. The order of the scripts is the one i posted but i will try now to change them a bit.

Comment: I've seen this error when I tried to call jQuery functions (_find_ is one of them) on a regular JS object by mistake. Is it possible that you try to do _this.find_ somewhere, instead of _$(this).find_ or something like that?

Comment: Why are you including **two** different versions of jQuery UI?

Comment: this.find is called in jquery.tinymce.js and jquery.validate.min.js other that i dont find somethink but this cant be the problem or?

Comment: @ Anthony: Because in the custom one where some features missing i replaced with 1.8.21 custom with all features. But problem still exists.